# native C++ dll/C# Problem of memory

Tags: c#, c++, dll, memory-leaks, unmanaged

I have this error

**Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.**

Do you know why? I am realy stuck...

My Code :

**Native c++**

```
    extern "C" void __declspec(dllexport) Mafonc(string nom);

void __declspec(dllexport) Mafonc(string nom)
{
    string tom = nom;
}
```

**c#**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security;

namespace TradeInterface
{
    static class Program
    {
        [DllImport("TradeEngine.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi,
            CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall,
            ExactSpelling = true),
        SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
        public static extern void Mafonc(string nom);

        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            Mafonc("E:\\DossierProjet");

            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the definition of string in your unmanaged DLL? If it is a character pointer, as I am guessing, then you can't just copy the pointer and use it later, but need to copy the string itself (strcpy or similar).

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. In my C++ code the string is a real string coming from String.h.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> in my C++ code the string is a real string coming from String.h.

There is no type named "string" in the `<string.h>` header, only std::string from `<string>`.  The pinvoke marshaller cannot create C++ objects.  You must use a C string:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
void Mafonc(const char* nom)
{
    std::string tom(nom);
}
```

Which requires this declaration in C#:

```
    [DllImport("TradeEngine.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern void Mafonc(string nom);
```

Note that the string conversion is lossy.  You can use const wchar_t* and std::wstring to avoid that.

Comment: Note that when marshalling strings, it is best to explicitly state the unmanaged type you want using the MarshalAs attribute.

Comment: Thank you, it's work now. I have many problems with a little string how I will do to build my application? Grrr. :( Do you think build a proxy C++/CLI dll between native code and C# can be faster and secured for me? We can said I am a noob.

Comment: The communication via an C++/CLI DLL won't necessarily be faster, since the data still needs to be marshalled. In general, marshalling is somewhat slow => if possible you should have "chunky" rather than "chatty" interfaces, i.e. have few calls with larger amounts of data rather than many calls with little data.

Comment: I am doing an application with winform in C# and the core must be in C++ so for you the best is to build the app in C++ with Win32 or continue to use WinForm.(Win32 scared me) (Sorry if it is not realy about the first question)

Answer (score 2):

> extern "C" void __declspec(dllexport) Mafonc(string nom);

Admittedly, I'm not 100% up on exactly how `extern "C"` works, but I'm pretty sure you're not allowed to call it with a C++ type. I assume that this is a `std::string`, but you didn't put the namespace qualification on it.

I'm *very* certain that, even if you could use a std::string there, C# doesn't pass `std::string`s around. In .NET, strings are a different kind of object. So you would need some special marshalling code to do the conversion to a type that C++ understands.

Or is what you label as "C++" really a C++/CLI application? Because that's something different.

Comment: My C++ dll is a unmanaged/native C++ Dll. Even without extern 'C' I have the same problem. What I need to do?

Comment: @Nazka: You need to learn how to send strings from a managed executable to a native DLL. I guarantee you that it won't involve the native DLL using a C++ class; more than likely, it will take a `char*` or `TCHAR*`.

Answer (score 1):

Since ypu are populating the string in C++, you sould pass a StringBuilder as a parameter. Ie try with this:

```
[DllImport("TradeEngine.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi,
            CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall,
            ExactSpelling = true),
        SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
        public static extern void Mafonc(StringBuilder nom);
```

Then are you sure the calling convention is correct ? Isn't CallingConvention.Cdecl ?

Comment: And how I wrote Mafonc("E:\\DossierProjet"); at the end because I have an 2 errors messages "The best overloaded method match for'TradeIn...' has some invalid arguments" and "cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Text.StringBuilder'.

Comment: @Nazka you have to change the c# code, create an instance of StringBuilder before calling the function, and pass to the function. Then use the ToString method to have back the required string.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot marshal a C++ std::string. See [marshalling strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8w969hb.aspx) and [UnmanagedType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.unmanagedtype.aspx) for the types you can marshal. So you need to marshal it as an UnmanagedType.LPStr or UnmanagedType.LPWStr, and change your unmanaged DLL. Additionally, the calling convention most probably is Cdecl. Putting this together:

```
void __declspec(dllexport) Mafonc(LPSTR nom)
{
    // Do something with nom
}
```

and

```
[DllImport(
    "TradeEngine.dll",
    CharSet = CharSet.Ansi,
    CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl,
    ExactSpelling = true),
    SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
public static extern void Mafonc([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string nom);
```

Comment: Ups I have this : "Unable to find an entry point named 'Mafonc' in DLL 'TradeEngine.dll'."

Comment: You of course also need the extern "C" part as well as the C# code where you use the method. I just wrote the parts which need to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Try following,

```
  [DllImport("TradeEngine.dll",CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
            private static  extern void Mafonc(StringBuilder data);
```

Where your native method is,

```
extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) void Mafonc(std::string data)
{
    string xyz=data;

}
```

**IJW**